# Using @masterthesis entry in .bib to use it in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I am making my slides with beamer and for the references, I'm referencing it to a .bib file. In that file I have the following entry:

```
@mastersthesis{kooshathesis,
  title={Disease-Gene Association Using a Genetic Algorithm},
  author={Tahmasebipour, Koosha},
  year={2014},
  school={Brock University}
}
```

My problem is that, in generated slides, it can't recognize `\cite{kooshathesis}` while there is no problem with other entries of my .bib file.

Is that a problem with @masterthesis ?

Edit: As it was suggested here, I'm including a MVE here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Marburg}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
I want to cite this work \cite{kooshathesis}, but it doesn't work!
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{References}      
   \tiny{\bibliographystyle{abbrv} }
    \bibliography{references}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using `biblatex` as citation package?

Comment: No I'm not, this is the references slide: `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{References}      
       \tiny{\bibliographystyle{abbrv} }
  \bibliography{references}
\end{frame}` should I use that package? @Johannes_B

Comment: The style actually knows that type, so i guess a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) is needed. Somebody will figure out what to do once your basic code is known.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I just edited the post. Do you see any problem there? @Johannes_B

Comment: your MWE example seems to work fine. To be sure: Did you run bibtex after adding the master thesis?

Comment: Yes I did, and I followed the LaTeX > BibTex > LaTex > LaTeX pattern to compile it! It's weird that it's working fine for other entries of my reference file! @samcarter

Comment: Sorry, then I have no idea, what might be the reason

Comment: Can you show us the output of the bibtex-log-file (blg)?

Comment: I took a look at that file and found the problem!! There was a double entry in .bib file and it was ignoring the rest! Thanks for your help! @Johannes_B

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the cause was a faulty database with some double entry.